# Where are my Power Window Relays?

Tags: mazda, power-windows

I have a 2005 Mazda 3, and I have located both the interior and exterior fuse box. Neither one of the fuse boxes have relays in it concerning the power windows.  Does anyone know where they are on this car? I think I need to replace one to get my window to go back up.

**UPDATE:** Is this circuit diagram telling me that the relays for my power windows are in the main switch on the driver side (diagram courtesy of AutoZone saying it is for my Mazda 3 2005)?

[image: AutoZone's Wire Diagram for Mazda 3 05]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your wiring diagram, the relay is inside the switch, and based on that it's not serviceable.

Based on the picture you posted [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3767/85)

[image]

That black square box on the switch (tyco) is the relay.

[Here is are the specs (PDF)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG4QFjAA&url=http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=V23084-X0000-A001&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN&ei=kSXhT5vDA4au9ATs792DDQ&usg=AFQjCNE4CG4yGI4ErryiXD1kXAPyFuiKAA&sig2=5NLyYjgcDjv0vFjm-UGq-Q)

[Here is a where you can buy it](http://octopart.com/v23084-c2002-a403-tyco+electronics-9539888)

Based on that I would say it's replaceable, with some soldering required. It would take some additional testing to know if it's the relay, or another part of the switch assembly that was causing the failure.

Comment: You are correct, the box labeled TYCO is a relay, its actually a Double Mini Relay (DMR). I ended up popping the top off of the switch below the DMR and found that the issue was in there. Thanks for the info on buying a DMR, when I initially searched for it based on part number I couldn't find it anywhere.  For informational purposes, it might be useful for others to see this video of someone de-soldering a DMR (similar part number) from their BMW, (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0zT2UtEU88) thought that takes more money than replacing (initially) and more knowledge of circuits than I have.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but have you looked through the switch circuitry? Sometimes those modules come all in one, and you have to replace it.

Comment: I don't know wire diagrams worth squat, can you tell me what the added diagram shows me?

Comment: @tarheel Like I suspected, and Larry verified, you need a switch module.

Comment: I ended up disassembling the main switch on the driver side, got the window back up by manipulating the switch for the window in question, but I think that was the last it will move, now it wont go up or down. Going to buy a new switch.