# Driver side window will not go up or down

Tags: electrical, mazda-3, power-windows, window

2007 Mazda 3 driver side window will not go up or down ,put new motor & switch in still does not work.Getting no power to driver side window

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While it may not provide an answer, [here's a related question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3788/4152).

Comment: Did you check the fuse?

Comment: Another thing to check is the wires for the window that are routed through the door hinge area.  They are prone to breaking or chaffing caused by the door constantly being opened and closed.