# How to remove Duct Tape residue?

Tags: cleaning, paint

I recently had my [window get stuck](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3767/my-2005-mazda-3-front-passenger-window-motor-receives-signal-to-go-down-but-not) only after having it rolled all the way down. So I had to put a trash bag in its place temporarily, to keep rain from damaging the interior of my vehicle, and it was held down by duct tape.  Now that the issue has been resolved, and my window is back up, I am trying to get the residue off of my car, without damaging the paint.  Does anyone know how to do that?

[image: Showing duct tape residue on my car door.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are "sticker removers" specifically for automotive use that should be able to soften the residue so you can get it off. I also had reasonable success with Autoglym tar remover. In either case, make sure you're using something that's safe on automotive paintwork.

Comment: The adhesive remover that I bought from 3M says it will not damage "most cured automotive paints". This may be a dumb question, but how do I know if my paints has been cured?

Comment: You're going to be OK - what they're basically saying applies only if the car has been freshly painted. If it hasn't been painted in the last 2-3 weeks, you can safely assume that the paint has cured. However, as always I'd check in an inconspicuous place to ensure that the adhesive remover isn't interacting with the paint.

Comment: It worked like a charm.  Just in case anyone else wants to know, I bought [this](http://www.amazon.com/3M-03618-Adhesive-Remover-oz/dp/B000BQYA7W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1341073656&sr=8-1&keywords=3m+adhesive+remover) and it worked great on the painted areas, did not affect my tinted windows, but did take a bit of the surface off of the plastic (around the side mirror).  So I switched to your standard Clorox Wipes to get that stuff off.

Comment: Could you please post a link or part number to the product you used? Timo Geusch?

Comment: http://www.autoglym.com/products/products/intensive-tar-remover

Answer (score 4):

I am a Pilot Car driver and have taped my sign on my pick up several times. When I remove it and the glue is left I use WD-40 and it removes the glue. It alse removes tar from your vehicle too.

Comment: Great point. Considering that WD-40 was originally designed as a cleaner for aircraft, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Duct tape — or Gorilla Tape — is awesome for heaps of things, yet it's not known for falling off neatly, especially if it's been hot.

I used to utilize CH3)2CO, at that point I changed to Goo Gone. Around five years prior, a temporary worker companion of our own said to utilize WD-40 — he swore it was better and substantially less expensive.

From that point forward, that is the thing that we've utilized. Furthermore, he was correct — it effectively expels tape buildup that took always with Goo Out of the picture.

Utilize a cloth with a touch of a surface to it — for instance, terry fabric instead of an old shirt — and douse a little zone of it with WD-40, at that point clean at the deposit. In the event that there is a considerable measure of tape gunk to get off and nothing adjacent that the WD-40 would hurt on the off chance that it ran or trickled, you can shower the deposit and let it sit for one moment before scouring.

Clearly, don't do this on anything that the oil in WD-40 would hurt! Subsequent to evacuating the deposit, I, for the most part, utilize a touch of cleanser and warm water to wash the region so it's not smooth from the WD-40. It's extremely essential to wash the WD-40 off on the off chance that you've gotten it anyplace that individuals will stroll as it is to a great degree tricky.

Comment: Welcome to [mechanics.se]. We noticed that you linked your own site, which looks promotional. Please state your affiliation with the site, otherwise it can be seen as an attempt at spamming, which we take it seriously, or otherwise remove it from the answer if it's not significant. For more info, please read [how to not be a spammer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the link as it doesn't add anything to the answer, and the poster has a link in his profile should people wish to use his services.

Answer (score 1):

A few drops of WD40, sponge off, all gone. Hose and wipe the WD40 off with clean sponge. Does not harm the paint. Very efficient with Rust-O-... automotive duct tape. Do you believe that? Next time, I won't use stupid duct tape but paint tape, which leaves no marks, costs the same and resists rain, cold and heat.

Answer (score 0):

Rubbing alcohol or vodka work well.  The alcohol evaporates but not before helping resolve the residue so you have no secondary residue from
The cleaning agent which you would be left with if you used a lot of degreasers or strippers, GooGone or Aircraft remover leave an oily residue.  Aircraft remover will strip everything, down to the bare metal, powder coat, urethane, oem paint which is usually urethane, etc.

Lighter fluid will work but only if you have a particular type of lighter fluid which contains naphtha, a solvent ingredient which is no longer used in many types of lighter fluid.